# ADA Payments for Ecommerce

Tags: payment

I am looking for plugins that integrate with Squarespace, Webflow, for custom websites to accept cryptocurrency payments including ADA.

The [NowPayments.io](https://nowpayments.io) plugin only works for a few e-commerce websites.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently also a solution by coti called adapay https://adapay.finance/ . Unfortunately, I think currently it's deployed as a tailored solution only.